# Handling dynamic elements in GraphQL schema

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I have a list of entities, and the entity has a base definition + for each country it adds a variable number of fields, and some of the country specific fields might be marked as required. When asking for this list of entities I want to get back data according to the schema, which is decided by the country field (part of the base definition). Similarly, when persisting data I want the correct entity schema to be applied.

How can I model this with graphql ?

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [interfaces](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces).

Something like this:

```
interface Entity {
   [ADD YOUR COMMON FIELDS HERE]
}

type SpanishEntity implements Entity {
    [ADD YOUR COMMON FIELDS HERE + THE FIELDS REQUIRED FOR SPAIN]
}

type FrenchEntity implements Entity {
    [ADD YOUR COMMON FIELDS HERE + THE FIELDS REQUIRED FOR FRANCE]
}
```